# UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups() does not retrieve all groups

Tags: .net, active-directory

I need to recursively search Active Directory groups to see if a user account is in a given group; however, some of the groups of which the user is a member were not returned by the GetAuthorizationGroups() method.

The function is:

```
public static bool IsUserAuthorized(string adGroup, string userName)
{
    bool isInRole = false;

    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain"))
    {
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
        {
            isInRole = user != null && user.GetAuthorizationGroups().Any(g => g.SamAccountName == adGroup);
        }
    }

    return isInRole;
}
```

I call the function as so:

```
IsUserAuthorized("myGroup", "MyDomain\MyUser");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a problem with the code.  The .GetAuthorizationGroups() method does not retrieve the groups that are set with a Group Type of Distribution.  I changed the Group Type in Active Directory from Distribution to Security.  And, magically, the missing group is returned by the .GetAuthorizationGroups() method.